# Specific resources to self-learn algebra

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm attempting to self-learn algebra/trig from the ground up and looking for good resources that will help.

Currently my goal is to learn enough to be able to take:

- MIT OCW Sing Var Calc
- MIT OCW Mathematics for CS
- Linear Algebra

I'm currently going through some of the material on Khan Academy but not sure if their content is sufficient for the above goal/an overkill

Essentially I am looking for a good route/content with links to resources that I can follow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [www.edx.org](https://www.edx.org/) - it hosts hundreds of courses, some of them at the high school level.

One that seems like what you're looking for is [Introduction to Algebra](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-algebra-schoolyourself-algebrax#!), which says it covers a standard curriculum in high school Algebra I. It is self-paced, so you can jump in any time you want.

After completing that, you may also find the following helpful to aid in the transition to MIT's calculus course:

- [Discovery Precalculus: A Creative and Connected Approach](https://www.edx.org/course/discovery-precalculus-creative-connected-utaustinx-ut-prec-10-01x) from
  University of Texas at Austin starts September 1
- [Pre-university Calculus](https://www.edx.org/course/pre-university-calculus-delftx-calc001x) from Delft University starts today, July
  14
- [AP Calculus Review](https://www.edx.org/course/apr-calculus-challenging-concepts-davidson-next-calapccx) from Davidson Next is self-paced starting
  July 21  (so you can start any time after that)

And by the way, MIT has its single-variable calculus course on edx:

- [Part 1 - Differentiation](https://www.edx.org/course/calculus-1a-differentiation-mitx-18-01-1x)
- [Part 2 - Integration](https://www.edx.org/course/calculus-1b-integration-mitx-18-01-2x)
- [Part 3 - Coordinate Systems and Infinite Series](https://www.edx.org/course/calculus-1c-coordinate-systems-infinite-mitx-18-01-3x)

Hope this helps!

Edit: Based on your comment below, I'm adding this [Introduction to Geometry](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-geometry-schoolyourself-geometryx#!) course to the list, as it may be helpful to take between algebra and pre-calculus.

I have not taken any of these courses so I can't tell you how "complete" this path would be, it's possible some of the trigonometry will fall through the cracks. I would imagine after taking the algebra and geometry courses you would have a good feel for whether you're ready for pre-calculus.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! The intro to algebra by edx looks good, but should I also not look for an equivalent that will cover high school Algebra 2 before moving onto some the pre-calc stuff mentioned above?

Comment: I added a geometry course to my original response that could possibly help with some of the trigonometry requirements of pre-calc. You are right that an algebra II course may be helpful. You will probably have a better idea of your comfort level after taking one or two of the above. Khan Academy is great and you could use it to fill in some of the gaps.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try out https://www.ixl.com/math/ When I was a tutor, I used this website with some of my students and they seemed to benefit from it a lot. It covers skills from pre-kindergarden through precalculus.